# How do I change the route provided to me by the directions API on web?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I don't know how to change the route manually provided to me by the route of the directions API.

I've been browsing the net for a while now and I haven't searched anything yet.

How will I manually change the route provided to me by the directions API? For example, If there is a traffic within the route, I want to change the route to avoid that traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible things you can do:

1. Request route alternatives when available (`provideRouteAlternatives: true`)
2. Set the `draggable` [DirectionsRendererOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRendererOptions) to `true` to allow to manually drag the route to change it.

Here is a complete example that shows both methods together in action:

```js
var directionsService;
var map;

function initialize() {

  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: center
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  var start = "Bordeaux, France";
  var end = "Valence, France";

  plotDirections(start, end);
}

function plotDirections(start, end) {

  var method = 'DRIVING';

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[method],
    provideRouteAlternatives: true
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      var routes = response.routes;
      var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black'];
      var directionsDisplays = [];

      // Reset the start and end variables to the actual coordinates
      start = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;
      end = response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location;

      // Loop through each route
      for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          map: map,
          directions: response,
          routeIndex: i,
          draggable: true,
          polylineOptions: {

            strokeColor: colors[i],
            strokeWeight: 4,
            strokeOpacity: .3
          }
        });

        // Push the current renderer to an array
        directionsDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);

        // Listen for the directions_changed event for each route
        google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', (function(directionsDisplay, i) {

          return function() {

            var directions = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
            var new_start = directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;
            var new_end = directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_location;

            if ((new_start.toString() !== start.toString()) || (new_end.toString() !== end.toString())) {

              // Remove every route from map
              for (var j = 0; j < directionsDisplays.length; j++) {

                directionsDisplays[j].setMap(null);
              }

              // Redraw routes with new start/end coordinates
              plotDirections(new_start, new_end);
            }
          }
        })(directionsDisplay, i)); // End listener
      } // End route loop
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try it immediately.

Comment: Did this not help? If it helped, you could possibly accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry I got another question. If the map is being by another user, will it update the route on his/her side as well?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. This is answer is the one I need but can I somehow pass the new route/direction to a database (I'm using firebase) so that the other user can use the route on his/her side? I'm using this for an application of a courier so that the courier can see the parcel's location.

Comment: That's a totally different question now. But you can extract the path that you need and temporarily store it in a database, of course.

Comment: is the path the response returned by the request? Is is recommended to store it? Any resource or tutorials you can give me?

BTW thank you for your continuous response.

Comment: The path is part of the response yes. You have the overview path, overview Polyline, and each Directions step contain the full Polyline path. You could store any of this **temporarily** probably. Check the Terms Of Service because there are things you are not supposed to store. Just look at the Directions [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) and search for "path".

Comment: I was able to change the route direction by storing and getting the **waypoints**. But it's returning me `waypoints.locations.lat` is not a function for some reason. I'm gonna find a way to somehow fix this error. Thank you very much for your help.